# Terminology: Can one say "The exponent $y$ in the power of 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to get a deeper understanding of how exponential and thus logarithm functions work. Can I describe the function $2^3$ so:

"The exponent 3 in the power of 2"

Comment: I would rather call $2^3$ a number than a "function". My english is not the best but I believe that "two raised to the power of three" or "the third power of two" are more common. I wonder if "two powered to three" is correct..

Comment: What does power mean in this context?

Comment: I think that "exponent" and "power" is more or less the same, in mathematical language.

Comment: No. I mean the base is 2, and the exponent is 3? However, the "whole thing" is written "The exponent 3 in the power of 2" or in the power, of 2 cubed?

Comment: No, when you say "The exponent 3 in the power of 2", I don't understand what you mean and I can't figure out if it is $2^3$ or $3^2$. It is much better to say "two [raised] to the third [power].

Comment: [[@Yves I would never interpret it as $3^2$ (unless I knew the speaker was bad with English) since three is the exponent (so it is superscript) and you're taking a power *of* two.]] The phrase "the exponent 3 in the power of 2" only makes sense if you're literally referring to the number 3 that appears in the expression $2^3$. For instance, suppose we are discussing cubefree numbers, and somewhere along the line we get to prime factorize a number and say "notice the exponent 3 in the power of 2." The phrase does not refer to "two taken to the power of three."

Comment: $2^3$ is a number, or a formal expression, but unless you're doing crazy stuff with the lambda calculus, it is **not** a function.

Comment: @blue: I agree with you, there is a single acceptable interpretation. A description of the "function" $2^3$ as "the exponent $3$ in the power of $2$" would leave me so puzzled that I would miss it. (Just as often as the notation of compound functions $f\circ g$ requires special attention.)

Comment: I have a Prentice Hall Classics Algebra and Trig 2006 book. It says: "In the expression "x^n", x is called the base; n is called the exponent; and "x^n" (the whole thing) is called the power.